# How do I pass JavaScript variables via FancyBox?

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I'm attempting to pass JavaScript variables via FancyBox, so that I can access them in the window that appears. So far, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s;
    var e;
    var fancyboxdata = new Array();
    $(function(){
        $('#post_code').blur(function(){
            s = $('#post_code').val();
        });
    });
    function map_routes(e){
        if ((s.length !== 0) && (e.length !== 0)) {
            document.getElementById('map_routes_button').style.visibility="visible";
            fancyboxdata[s] = s;
            fancyboxdata[e] = e;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('map_routes_button').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
    }
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.iframe_maps").fancybox({
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                data: fancyboxdata
            },
            'hideOnContentClick': true,
            'height': 600,
            'padding': 0,
            'width': 700, 
            'type': 'iframe'
        });
    });
</script>
```

At this stage, I know the fancyboxdata array contains data, but I'm unsure about the Ajax parameter in the FancyBox function, which is supposed to pass the array variable.

In the window that appears, I have:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

echo $_POST['s'];

?>
<script>
    (function() {
        alert(fancyboxdata[s]);
    })();
</script>
```

And nothing appears, other than empty arrays and errors in the debugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: what errors in the debugger ?

Comment: Just an explanation that the fancyboxdata array variable can't be found.

And in PHP:

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: s</p>
<p>Filename: bookings/maps.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 5</p>

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just listen for the submit of the form and an AJAX call separately as in this question (uses jQuery)?

[Can't get form data to post via AJAX using Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101442/cant-get-form-data-to-post-via-ajax-using-fancybox)

Comment: I might if I had any idea what you just said! I'm not in the least proficient with either JavaScript, Ajax, or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use like `data: "phpVar="+fancyboxdata`

fancyboxdata (it is your javascript array variable) and

phpVar {will call in your php page. It is holding fancyboxdata.}

for codeigniter-fancybox You try below code. may be it'

```
$.fancybox({
            'width'             : 900,
            'height'            : 390,
            'autoScale'         : true,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'href'              : 'page.php?id='+9,
            'type'              : 'iframe'
        });
```

and then use $_get['id']

Comment: I just tried that and CodeIgniter is reporting that phpVar is an undefined index.

Comment: have You used $_POST["phpVar"] in Your php page?

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work. I've tried: print_r($_POST), $phpVar, and $_POST["phpVar"]. None work.

Comment: I can't see how that would work. I don't (and probably can't) call a view in CodeIgniter directly. I could probably send the data to the method, via the controller, but then I'd have to push the data up to view somehow, which looks horribly complex.